# Are we no longer sponsored by Strangeworks?

Tags: discussion, graduation

I no longer see the "Sponsored by Strangeworks" ad at the top of the site:

[image]

Furthermore, for the first time, I've seen an AWS ad:

[image]

I thought the loss of the sponsorship ad at the top, might have had something to do with graduating yesterday, but AI.SE still has the sponsorship ad at the top:

[image]

Comment: that's been the case for quite some time actually. I think the sponsorship simply lasted one year or something like that

Comment: It certainly lasted more than 3 years.

Comment: I'm bad with dates. I'm sure the sponsorship thing was removed quite some time ago, but have no real idea how long. I'll look for a more precise date

Answer (score 1):

The sponsorship lasted until around May 2021, as judged from the web archive snapshots in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341663/276202 (I tried to get a more precise date but the site is slow and my patience run out quickly).

Comment: Why is a web archive needed? The link literally says "from March 12th, 2018 until about May 21st, 2021" [which is more than 3 years](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/521/are-we-no-longer-sponsored-by-strangeworks/522#comment2938_521). Can you confirm for sure that this ad was a consequence of graduation? You indicated [here in April 2021](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/476/2293) that you weren't aware of the fact that we had ads on the site, but we did have them back then.

Comment: I don't understand the first question. The person in the link got that date from the web archive, is my understanding. With more patience, you can get a more precise date if you really want to. For example, it seems that on May 22th it was still sponsored. Ads-wise you might be right. I'm probably too used at this point to the various adblocks and keep forgetting ads exist. The mother meta post does mention one of the consequences of graduation being to "be eligible for community ads in 2022" though.

Comment: lol. "community ads" are ads that community members like you and me make. They are made by users of the site who have enough reputation. They weren't allowed on QCSE because we were in Beta, but we'll get them in 2022.  The screenshot in my question is an ad made by Amazon! As for the web archive: clicking "next" shows that on May 30th the sponsorship was gone, and this would be precisely why the Meta post says it was sponsored until about May 21st (no snapshots are available between 21st and 30th).

Comment: @user1271772 yep, that seems accurate, thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks!